# css transition doesn't work on chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension, when user click on the button I am loading a custom popup window from my content div

```
/contentScript.js

var contentDiv = `
<div id='mydiv-container'>
   <div id="test"></div>
</div>`;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage (request, sender, sendResponse) {
$("body").append(contentDiv);
$('#mydiv-container').addClass('visible');
}
```

This works, problem is that I use a css transition that doesn't work

```
/content.css

#mydiv-container {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 390px;
    width: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    top: -200px;
    z-index: 999999999;
    transition: all 2s;
}

#mydiv-container.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 20px;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

This doesn't work as it expected, the transition is not taking place.
How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Webkit is the property of CSS supported by google chrome

```
-webkit-transition: all 2s;
```

Comment: can you post HTML

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that with the use of the `setTimeout` method.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#mydiv-container').addClass('visible');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using Webkit works for me and when i try to copy your code on a jsfiddle didnt work because the mydivcontainer was on top of the button so the button never triggers so i change the `top: -200px;` to `top: -400px`

https://jsfiddle.net/jvgx4ucj/1/